# Make a date field static after mail merge using Word

Tags: microsoft-word, date, mail-merge

I often have to deal with mail merging (at least once a month).
I use a dynamic field for inserting the *Date*, the problem is the dynamic field remains such even after mail merging when you save the result as a file showing the date of the current day!

I know I could hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> on the field to make it become static text... but I don't want to do that for every document obtained as merging result!

I tried to look at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-the-date-and-time-a-document-was-created-last-printed-or-last-saved-a2c4e3cc-b096-4c50-9395-5dca9f3beed1 :

*SAVEDATE* or *PRINTDATE* wouldn't be good as I could save/print the document days later, subsequently losing the original date, so... *CREATEDATE* maybe? 
Well... No: a *CREATEDATE* field will show the date of when the "original" mail-merge document (not the output) was created! (Plus it may still change if you save the document into a new one using "Save As".)
What can I do then?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, as I think this could be useful:

It is possible to make a `DATE` field to turn to a static text as result of mail-merging process in Word by using `{ QUOTE { DATE } }` in the mail merge main document.
This way, you'll get the date when the mail-merging output has been created.

AN IMPORTANT NOTE: Just remember you can't simply type the curly brackets directly but must use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> key combination.